# ScrollView cut off part of the display.

Tags: java, android

I tried to delete margins and added a padding button, but those showed no effect.  I'm using ScrollView with Relative layout inside of it but when I lunch emulator it shows that part of my screen is cut off. I read similar articles about it but they couldn't help me.

```
`<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding_bottom="10dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_update"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_update"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_year"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_genres"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_year"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_year"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_year"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_runtime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_genres"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_genres"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_genres"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_about"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_runtime"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_runtime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_runtime"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_about"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_about"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_about"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_rating"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_rating"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_rating"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ĮKELTI"
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:background="#ffcb4e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ŽIŪRĖTI"
        android:id="@+id/button_viewAll"
        android:background="#ffcb4e"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ATNAUJINTI"
        android:id="@+id/button_update"
        android:background="#ffcb4e"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ištrinti"
        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_update"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_viewAll"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_viewAll"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#ffcb4e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pavadinimas:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText_year" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Metai:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_year"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_year" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Žanras:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_genres"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_year"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_year"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_genres"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_year" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Trukmė:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_runtime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_genres"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_genres"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_genres"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_runtime" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Aprašymas:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_about"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_runtime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_runtime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_runtime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_about" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Įvertinimas:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_about"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_about"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_about"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_rating" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ID:"
        android:id="@+id/textView_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_rating"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_rating"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_rating"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>`
```

This is how it looks in [emulator](http://clip2net.com/s/3tflKEi). It is hard to see, but the view is cut right after the last button.

Comment: You should be put the complete layout

Comment: Link not working to screenshot but

you can use `constraint layout` as parent 

`ConstraintLayout -> ScrollView -> RelativeView -> Other Views`

You can easily give padding or margin

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Here is a nice reference:
[Romain Guy's trick with ScrollView](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: No, it doesnt really help, it didnt really changed anything.

Comment: set height to wrap_parent as well when using fillViewPort

Comment: Also, combine what Jose said. This type of layout you have designed is very simply (and more succinctly) done with a LinearLayout since it is structured in a linear fashion. RelativeLayout is the fall back when you have widgets that don't stack in a linear way (both vertically or horizontally).

Answer (score 1):

The **structure** of your layout is wrong. I would do something like this:

```
<ScrollView>

  //Layout father
  <LinearLayout orientation="vertical"...>

      //Automatically aligned one under the other
      <EditText/>//No layout_below, no layout_align
      <EditText/>
      <EditText/>
      <EditText/>...

      <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal"...>
          //If the width is 0 and weight 1, each button will occupy half of the screen
          <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1".../>
          <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1".../>
      </LinearLayout>

      //And so on...

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use padding attribute in scroll view that will help

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank view as last item under scroll view.
Example:

```
    <ScrollView 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <LinearLayout 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:orientation="vertical">

                        <View 
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="56dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview can only host one direct child

Comment: @mohamedaouledissa i mean the view will be present under direct child of scroll view. Updated my answer.